# Separator Between Items in LongListSelector on WP

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone

I Have a LongListSelector which is bonded to a contact list , i would like to add a little line to separate each contacts .

Here is my xaml :

```
  <phone:LongListSelector>
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding informations}"  Height="120" />
                        <Image  Source="{Binding photo}"   Height="90" Width="90"  />
                        <Line Fill="Red" Height="2" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

But there is no red line between the items, how can I add one?

EDIT :

Does it have to do with the fact that the orientation of my StackPanel is Horizontal?

Comment: Did you try adding `Width="90"` to `Line` element?

Comment: Lines can be a pain to use. If its just a separator I would use Rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the "Horizontal".

Try this:

```
    <phone:LongListSelector>
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel> 
                    <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding informations}"  Height="120" />
                        <Image  Source="{Binding photo}"   Height="90" Width="90"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Line Fill="Red" Height="2" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above solution didn't work so here is an alternate solution:

```
<phone:LongListSelector>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel> 
                 <StackPanel>
                     <TextBlock  Text="{Binding informations}"  Height="120" />
                     <Image  Source="{Binding photo}"   Height="90" Width="90"  />
                 </StackPanel>
                 <Rectange Fill="Red" Height="2"  width="120"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector>
```