# Show partition around each item of longlistselector in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to show partition around each item of longlistselector like listview in android. I am unable to find any relevant data. All people are showing data without showing partition line etc.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="playerList"
                IsGroupingEnabled="False" LayoutMode="List" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         Width="446">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding info}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

I want to show some kind of partition around TextBlock

Comment: There are some examples already on stackO - look for seperator and longlistselector : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940716/separator-between-items-in-longlistselector-on-wp

Comment: not working ,. i also tried that was there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a border in your listpicker datatemplate.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```