# Windows Phone 8 XAML- How to create Line?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have this:

[image]

with this code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
                            Content="Zapnout senzory"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="2"/>    
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

and I'd like to use Line instead of the Rectangle, but when i write this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}"
                            Content="Zapnout senzory"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Line Fill="Black" Stroke="Black" 
                      Height="2" StrokeThickness="5"/>    
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

there is no line. Any ideas how to do it?

And in next part of the app, I'd like to have this:

[image]

line next to the button and I dont have idea how to do it.
I want to use this app on different displays, so it has to be relative.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940716/separator-between-items-in-longlistselector-on-wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a `<canvas/>` control in your stackpanel, if you want to define the exact position (in the canvas) for the line.

If you just want to add a "break" line in your stackpanel, use a rectangle with Width="xyz" and Height="1"

HTH